# Rapberry Pi GPIO extension with node.js

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, gpio, pigpio

I am working on a project with my raspberry pi that needs more than 16 pins. I am planning to use a few mcp23017 microchips to expand my gpio ports. I am currently working in node.js with the onoff module to use the gpio how would I make this work? Should I use pigpio instead?

Comment: How many pins do you need? The Pi has 28 GPIO pins.

Comment: I need about 40-50, and I know there is a smaller microchip but I am planning to use this for other projects later as well

Comment: You should enable driver in the Linux kernel for this chip. Then it will be accessible via standard GPIO ABIs.